# Show that $\mu=\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q<0\} \cup\left\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q^{2}<2\right\}$ is a dedekind cut

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$\mu=\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q<0\} \cup\left\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q^{2}<2\right\}$

I did this:

$\mu$ is not equal to $\mathbb{Q}$

Is true that if  $q \in \mu$ and $p< q$ then $p \in \mu$ but I don't know how to prove it

and the last is true too, because for every q in  $\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q<0\}$

$\frac{q}{2}<0$ and $\frac{q}{2}>q$ then $\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q<0\}$ has no a maximum and for
$\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q^{2}<2\}$

$\frac{q^{2}+2}{2}<2$

is this right?

Comment: You have made nice attempt. The main issue is in last part as that is tricky and non-trivial.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3937003/72031)